# allow access to certain folder/files only for some users

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permissions, web

I have a Weblication which provides access to certain pages only to some users. Now there are some files linked on these pages. If someone has the URL everyone can access these files (in this case the search engines). This should be changed! How can I protect such a directory? I thought about two possibilites:

- htaccess: Enter username + password every time a new user is created -> not suitable for that type of project (would also need a second login)
- download.php?file=xxx: Don't know how to include such one on all Links in Weblication (static pages)

Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on "Don't know how to include such one on all Links in Weblication" so I can attempt at a more detailed answer.

Comment: Weblication is built of static pages. But since it is a CMS the user can edit the content, but it is still a static page. So I don't know how to add a download.php for all download links for existing pages and for future content of the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken and translated from [this link](http://dev4.weblication.de/wDev/knowledgebase/articles/20040609_artikel_persausgabe_modrewrite.php) (but is only available in the [WaybackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301134309/http://dev4.weblication.de/wDev/knowledgebase/articles/20040609_artikel_persausgabe_modrewrite.php)).

## Personalised output with the help of mod_rewrite

With the help of the function `wCheckPermissionViewFile` php files can be personalized. It is sufficient to perform the permission check in the header of a file to suppress the output. If other file types should be personalised (e.g. ZIP, PDF, ...), `wPermission.cgi` or a custom php file can be used.

To save the editor some work for writing `wPermission.cgi` before every personalised link to a binary file, instead the Apache module `mod_rewrite` can be used. With this it is possible to convert every accessed link before execution. For example you could define that `wPermission.cgi` is in front of each webserver call. The direct execution could also be redirected with the help of a php file (no `wPermission.cgi` necessary).

### Example of a `.htaccess` file via check from Perl (`wPermission.cgi`)

```
#Alle Dateien mit angegebener Endung über wPermission.cgi aufrufen.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .pdf$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .doc$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .xls$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .ppt$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .pps$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .zip$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .jpg$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .jpeg$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .png$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .gif$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /cgi-bin/wPermission.cgi?file=/de/dokumente/$1
```

### Example of a `.htacces` file via check from PHP (e.g. *download.php*, see below)

```
#Alle Dateien mit angegebener Endung über die angegebene PHP-Datei aufrufen.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .pdf$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .doc$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .xls$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .ppt$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .pps$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .zip$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .jpg$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .jpeg$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .png$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .gif$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /de/download.php?path=/de/dokumente/$1
```

### Explanation

If you would like to personalise all PDF and ZIP files within the directory `/de/dokumente` without changing the links, you could put a `.htaccess` file into that directory. In this file the redirect rules are defined.

The rules can be extended with arbitrary file extensions, `NC` stands for *non case sensitive*. Be aware that the rules are also inherited onto sub directories.

The binary files itself have to be checked in and provided with the according personalisation.

If you would like to check if the file is in a valid publishing time period (e.g. online or offline), then do the check before the permission check via PHP API `wIsOnline`.

#### Example: *download.php* for the implementation "`.htacces` file via check from PHP (e.g. *download.php*)"

```php
<?php

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dieses Skript erzwingt den Download von Dokumenten. PDF, DOC, XLS und PPT Dokumente werden je nach Browser angezeigt.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Einlesen der Weblication(r) 4.x API:
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/weblication/lib/WAPI/WAPI.inc");

$filenameRel = str_replace("..", "", $_GET['path']);
$filename    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filenameRel;

if(preg_match("/\.\w+$/", $filename) && !preg_match("/\.(php|php5|php4|xml|xsl|cgi|pl)$/", $filename) && !preg_match("/\/weblication\//", $filename) &&  file_exists( $filename ) ){
  if(wCheckPermissionViewFile($filenameRel) == 1){
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    if(preg_match("/\.pdf/i", $filenameRel)){
      header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    }
    else if(preg_match("/\.doc/i", $filenameRel)){
      header("Content-Type: application/msword");
    }
    else if(preg_match("/\.xls/i", $filenameRel)){
      header("Content-Type: application/msexcel");
    }
    else if(preg_match("/\.ppt/i", $filenameRel)){
      header("Content-Type: application/mspowerpoint");
    }
    else if(preg_match("/\.pps/i", $filenameRel)){
      header("Content-Type: application/mspowerpoint");
    }
    else if(preg_match("/\.jpg/i", $filenameRel)){
      header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    }
    else if(preg_match("/\.jpeg/i", $filenameRel)){
      header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    }
    else if(preg_match("/\.png/i", $filenameRel)){
      header("Content-Type: image/png");
    }
    else if(preg_match("/\.gif/i", $filenameRel)){
      header("Content-Type: image/gif");
    }
    else{
      header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
      header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
    }
    readfile($filename);
  }
  else{
    print "Permission Denied!";
  }
}
else {
  print 'Sorry, wrong path or file does not exist on the server!';
  print '<br/><a href="javascript:history.back();">back</a>';
}
exit;

?>
```

For newer versions of `Weblication` [this link](https://dev.weblication.de/dev/blog/download-von-sensiblen-daten-sicher-umsetzen.php) could help. It is in German, because the manufacturers main language is German.

Comment: That page doesn't exist anymore. It redirects straight to a splash page https://dev.weblication.de/ - it's also non-English.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This was an old post from me, where I didn't realized how bad link only answers were. The CMS I used main language is German, and also the manufacturers main language is German, but I thought code itself isn't really language sensitive. I updated my answer and included a translation.

Comment: That is excellent, thanks for that :-) *Cheers* and you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could store all of your file in a ***non public*** directory and then write a page (much like you say with download.php?file=xxx) that checks the user has permission to access the file and then output to the browser.

***Edit:***

As you are using a CMS, I would presume that the user has a nice GUI that they can click to choose the file they wish to insert/link to? If this is the case, you could probably find the code that it uses to create the link and then prepend `http://www.whatever.com/download.php?file=` to the filename which would then route the download through your script.

Comment: I think that's already named in the question and TS looks for alternatives to that.

Comment: I wasn't sure so I posted it anyway. I've asked him to elaborate a bit too.

Comment: No problem, this might even clarify something for the TS, just wanted to let you know how I did understand the question.

Comment: @Chief17: Thanks for your answer. I answered your question. As mentioned I'd have problems integrating the download.php in the CMS ...

Comment: @hakre: Why do you deleted your answer? I think it is still useful (it only didn't help me in my case).

Comment: @testing check my edit, hopefully you can use my suggestion :)

Comment: @Chief17: That would be an solution, since the CMS uses PHP scripts (you can switch to cgi scripts). What about the existing links? I would need to adapt all links and add the download.php only than when a file is accessed. And the current folder needs to be renamed so it isn't accessible anymore for the one who already has the file link.

Comment: I guess you could write a regular expression to find all of the links that are files (ie all files ending in pdf/zip etc...) and prepend the download link to them